cleveref not working for label after caption in longtable
Here is a simple example of the problem:
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

    
\begin{longtable}{l|p{11cm}}
    \caption{Parameters Added In Changes}\label{tab:offset_parameters}\\
       \toprule
      Parameter&Mnemonic\\
      \midrule
      A&B\\\hline
      E&F\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

Now I will reference it \Cref{tab:offset_parameters}. 
Note: Instead of indicating the table as Table \ref{tab:offset_parameters}, 
it is showing the null section name.

\end{document}

produces:

How can I fix?

Welcome to TeX.SE.

Unrelated, but you should not combine booktabs with vertical rules

Edit 2024-11-03
The suggested patch has been added as firstaid to LaTeX. With a LaTeX format newer than 2024-11-01 it is no longer needed to add it manually to documents.
Old answer
The problem is that cleveref patches \refstepcounter to update its data, but in a current LaTeX longtable doesn't use \refstepcounter directly (it does it avoids that hyperref anchors are set in the wrong place).
I think (but it is not much tested) that the following can replace the cleveref patch:
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,hidelinks]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cref@smugglelabel{\let\cref@currentlabel\cref@gcurrentlabel@temp}
\newcommand\cref@updatelabeldata[1]{%
 \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@gcurrentlabel@temp{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \aftergroup\cref@smugglelabel  
    }
% test if \@currentcounter is empty for unnumbered sections 
% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/728247/again-on-longtable-vs-cleveref-incompatibility
\AddToHook{label}{\ifx\@currentcounter\@empty\else\cref@updatelabeldata{\@currentcounter}\fi} 
 
\makeatother   
\begin{document}
 \section{a section}\label{sec:sec}   
\begin{longtable}{l|p{11cm}}
    \caption{Parameters Added In Changes\label{tab:offset_parameters}}\\
       \toprule
      Parameter&Mnemonic\\
      \midrule
      A&B\\\hline
      E&F\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

Now I will reference it \Cref{tab:offset_parameters} in \Cref{sec:sec}. 
Note: Instead of indicating the table as Table \ref{tab:offset_parameters}, 
it is showing the null section name.

\end{document}



Your patch replacement works like a charm. Thank you. Hope others find this useful.

In my case after applying the patch, the compiler stops at every label with the following comment:
You can't use `\relax' after \the.  \c@chapter

@ArtemijKeidan ask a new question with a proper example.

@UlrikeFischer thank you so much for the patch. Eventually I tried putting it after the first occurrence of \section (rather than in the preamble), and now it works without errors.

@ArtemijKeidan please make an example of the failing example so that one analyze the problem. I won't be able to add this patch to the LaTeX firstaid code if there is a danger that it breaks somewhere.

@happy_biker see my edit

@ArtemijKeidan see my edit
