Again on longtable vs. cleveref incompatibility
Ulrike Fischer has provided a patch to cleveref in order to improve the compatibility with longtable, see this question/answer. However, it seems not working properly when an unnumbered section is included, see my minimal code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\cref@smugglelabel{\let\cref@currentlabel\cref@gcurrentlabel@temp}
\newcommand\cref@updatelabeldata[1]{%
 \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@xdef\cref@gcurrentlabel@temp{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \aftergroup\cref@smugglelabel  
    }
\AddToHook{label}{\cref@updatelabeldata{\@currentcounter}} 
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\section*{Unnumbered section}\label{intro:sec}
 
\subsection*{Unnumbered subsection}
\begin{longtable}{l|p{11cm}}
    \caption{Parameters Added In Changes\label{tab:offset_parameters}}\\
       \toprule
      Parameter&Mnemonic\\
      \midrule
      A&B\\\hline
      E&F\\\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

Reference to \Cref{tab:offset_parameters}.


\end{document}


hm, yes \@currentcounter is empty then. I need to check what the original code is meant to do in this case.

well logic says that as cleverref patches refstepcounter the code is not needed if there was no refstepcounter. So change that to \AddToHook{label}{\ifx\@currentcounter\@empty\else\cref@updatelabeldata{\@currentcounter}\fi} (I will edit the other answer).

Dear @UlrikeFischer thank you so much for the solution. I think there are also some issues with polyglossia package. With your patch the names of the labels are displayed in English rather than in the main language of the document (e.g. "Table" instead of the Italian "Tabella" in my case).

I hate to have to repeat it: Do not ask new questions in comments. If you have a new question ask a new question with a proper example.
